# Efficient way to write many lines?

Tags: python

I have a txt file,around 20000 lines.I have to process every line and do some process,like replace some special string, then write the content to a new txt.
Now my process way is to save the content to a list, original_list.After process I get a new list process_list.
Write to a file:

```
with open('new.txt','w') as f1,
   for eachline in process_list:
       f1.write(eachline)
```

I think it is a very slow way to write each line to a file. So I want to know the efficient way. Like write 5000 lines every time? I guess.

Comment: Why do you believe this is slow? The file is only opened once and has buffered output so you don't control when it gets written to disk.

Comment: I just guess it will consume more memory to call I/O writing each line to file.My friend suggest me write 5000 line per time.

Comment: @EvanZhang Unless you are already having issues with speed, no need to pre-optimize

Comment: "I think it is a very slow way" - Why? Was it too slow for your purposes, at which point you tested it and determined that this particular bit of code was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The typical way of doing this would be the following:

```
with open('inFile.txt') as fIn:
    with open('outFile.txt', 'w') as fOut:
        for line in fIn:
            fOut.write(process(line))
```

This creates an iterator, is fast and is considered the best practice. Are you doing a block-type operation? It appears that you are doing line operations for which the above would suffice ...

Comment: I think this iterator is nice. I need not to create the list, and I can do the line operations in the iterator.

Comment: After processed the whole lines, using '/n' to connect eachline, and write 5000 lines per time ,like str_output= 'line1\n'+'line2\n+..'line5000\n'. And then write this very long string to the file. Is it efficient?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't have any data to back that up, but typical implementations of Python does that automatically for you in the background when you are using an iterator.